# new to scala & sbt - trying to compile a project that imports akka.stm._

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I'm new to Scala & sbt, and I'm trying to compile a project that imports *akka.stm._*.

When I try running *sbt compile* the compilation fails with a message point to that point.

I tried using
https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras
so I'll have the exact sbt version defined in the "build.sbt" file, but it did not help.

I downloaded the akka-2.0.3.tgz and opened the files, but I don't understand exactly how to install them by default or how to tell sbt to use them.

I also noticed that the build.sbt file contains:

```
resolvers += "repo.codahale.com" at "http://repo.codahale.com"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
//  "com.codahale" % "simplespec_2.9.0-1" % "0.3.4"
  "com.codahale" % "simplespec_2.9.0-1" % "0.4.1"
//  "se.scalablesolutions.akka" %% "akka-sbt-plugin" % "2.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

I tried uncommenting out the "se.scalablesolutions.akka" (assuming the programmer used the akka-library of that version), but it only printed the message:

```
[error] Error parsing expression.  Ensure that there are no blank lines within a setting.
```

(There are no blank lines, I just deleted the '//' and replaced the double '%' with a single one)

How do I tell the sbt to find the akka jar files in their place? Can I add another *resolver* to solve this problem?

I know this kind of question doesn't fit in stackoverflow, but can you at least refer me to some manuals I should read inorder to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, first of all I want to apologize for the newbie question.
(Stackoverflow should make a separate "newbie" section)

First, the elements in the *Seq* part should be separated by comma.
Second, the akka snapshots were moved to http://repo.akka.io/snapshots so I fixed the build.sbt to:

```
resolvers += "repo.codahale.com" at "http://repo.codahale.com"
resolvers += "akka" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
//  "com.codahale" % "simplespec_2.9.0-1" % "0.3.4"
  "com.codahale" % "simplespec_2.9.0-1" % "0.4.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-stm" % "2.0-SNAPSHOT" 
)
```

And the compilation finished successfully.

I don't know if this is the exact configuration in which the original compilation was done, but this issue doesn't disturb me at the moment.

Comment: Being a newbie on Stack Overflow is absolutely no problem, and your question was perfectly clear. It could have been improved with the link to the project you are trying to build, if it's publicly available.